# Selecting max date from multiple tables based upon a common FK

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I believe I finally have a working query for my situation today. I am endeavouring to select the maximum date across multiple tables based upon a `UserID + VendorID`. (Then update each LastActivityAt per `UserID`.

However, as soon as I introduce the `MAX()` on `PageStatistics` which can contain many entries, as it's a running log (essentially user activity) my query jumps from <1s to ~30 seconds.

Any suggestions on how I can improve this, or re-write the whole thing faster?

```
--UPDATE [UserRoleMappings] SET LastActivityAt =
    --(
SELECT UserID, MAX(CheckDate) AS MaxDate
FROM (
  SELECT urm.UserID, (
    SELECT Max(v) 
    FROM (VALUES
      (urm.LastLoginAt), (u.UpdatedAt), (u.CreatedAt), (b.CreatedAt), (o.CreatedAt), 
      ((
         SELECT MAX(CreatedAt) 
         FROM [PageStatistics] ps 
         WHERE ps.TriggerUserID = u.ID 
         AND ps.AppID = a.ID
       ))
    ) AS value(v)
  ) AS CheckDate
  FROM [UserRoleMappings] urm
    INNER JOIN [Users] u ON u.ID = urm.UserID
    INNER JOIN [Vendors] v ON v.ID = urm.VendorID
    INNER JOIN [Apps] a ON v.ID = a.VendorID
    INNER JOIN [Bookings] b ON v.ID = b.VendorID
    INNER JOIN [Orders] o ON v.ID = o.VendorID
) foo
GROUP BY UserID
    --)
```

Additionally, no idea how I'm going to bring this back to UPDATE... as I can't select two columns!

Answer (score 0):

Query.(MSSQL Join update)

```
with data as (
SELECT
UserID, MAX(CheckDate) AS MaxDate
FROM
(
    SELECT urm.UserID, (SELECT Max(v) 
    FROM (VALUES (urm.LastLoginAt), (u.UpdatedAt), (u.CreatedAt), (b.CreatedAt), (o.CreatedAt) 
        ,((SELECT MAX(CreatedAt) FROM [PageStatistics] ps WHERE ps.TriggerUserID = u.ID AND ps.AppID = a.ID))) AS value(v)) AS CheckDate
    FROM [UserRoleMappings] urm
        INNER JOIN [Users] u ON u.ID = urm.UserID
        INNER JOIN [Vendors] v ON v.ID = urm.VendorID
        INNER JOIN [Apps] a ON v.ID = a.VendorID
        INNER JOIN [Bookings] b ON v.ID = b.VendorID
        INNER JOIN [Orders] o ON v.ID = o.VendorID
) foo
GROUP BY UserID
)
UPDATE [UserRoleMappings] SET LastActivityAt = b.MaxDate
FROM [UserRoleMappings] a INNER JOIN data b ON b.UserID = a.UserID
```

subquery.

```
UPDATE [UserRoleMappings] SET LastActivityAt = (
    SELECT (SELECT Max(v) 
    FROM (VALUES (urm.LastLoginAt), (u.UpdatedAt), (u.CreatedAt), (b.CreatedAt), (o.CreatedAt) 
        ,((SELECT MAX(CreatedAt) FROM [PageStatistics] ps WHERE ps.TriggerUserID = u.ID AND ps.AppID = a.ID))) AS value(v)) AS CheckDate
    FROM [UserRoleMappings] urm
        INNER JOIN [Users] u ON u.ID = urm.UserID
        INNER JOIN [Vendors] v ON v.ID = urm.VendorID
        INNER JOIN [Apps] a ON v.ID = a.VendorID
        INNER JOIN [Bookings] b ON v.ID = b.VendorID
        INNER JOIN [Orders] o ON v.ID = o.VendorID
   WHERE urm.UserID = a.UserID
)
FROM [UserRoleMappings] a
```

Comment: Hi JuSun, thanks. Receiving error The multi-part identifier "a.UserID" could not be bound.

Comment: Ok find that. thank you that addresses my ability to update. But the query is still taking 30 seconds to load. Appreciating the help..

Comment: Any ideas on how to improve the PageStatistics subquery?